# For a triangular array, if $\max_{1\le k\le n}x_{n,k}\to 0$ and $\sum _{k=1} ^nx_{n,k}\to \lambda$ does $\prod_{k=1}^n(1+x_{n,k })\to e^{\lambda}$?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

Consider the following: we have a triangular array of nonnegative numbers
$$x_{1,1 }
\\x_{2,1 } \ x_{2,2 } 
\\ x_{3,1 } \ x_{3,1 }  \ x_{3,3 } 
\\... $$

The maximum on each row converges to zero: $\max_{1 \le k \le n } x_{n,k }\to 0$, and the sequence of row sums converges to $\lambda > 0 $: $\sum _{k=1 } ^n x_{n,k }  \to \lambda$ as $n \to \infty $.

> Does it follow that 
>   $$\prod_{k=1 } ^n (1+x_{n,k } ) \to e^{\lambda }\ ?$$

My hunch is that for $n $ large  $x_{n,k } $ shoud be close to $\frac {\lambda } {n } $ and thus $\prod_{k=1 } ^n (1+x_{n,k } ) \to e^{\lambda } $ is close to $(1+\frac {\lambda } {n })^n $ which approaches $e^{\lambda } $.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. As $0\leqslant x-\ln(1+x)\leqslant x^2/2$ for $x\geqslant 0$, we have
$$0\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^{n}\big(x_{n,k}-\ln(1+x_{n,k})\big)\leqslant\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{n,k}^2\leqslant\frac{1}{2}(\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}x_{n,k})\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{n,k}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$
which implies $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(1+x_{n,k})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{n,k}=\lambda$ and your claim.

Comment: Thanks! Is $x - \ln (1+x) \le x^2/2 $ a standard result?

Comment: I think so. Anyway it is obtained by doing $\int_0^x$ of the obvious $1-1/(1+t)[=t/(1+t)]\leqslant t$.

Comment: Thanks! I believe there is a minor typo. We have $\frac {1 } {2 } \sum _{k=1 } ^n x_{n,k } ^2 \le \frac {1 } {2 } \sum _{k=1 } ^n x_{n,k }  \to 0 $ which holds by letting $n $ be so large that $\max_{1 \le k \le n } x_{n,k } \le 1 $.

Comment: No typo here, I've used $x_{n,k}^2\leqslant x_{n,k}\cdot\displaystyle\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}x_{n,k}$. (And I don't see how do you justify your "$\to 0$".)

Comment: Got it! Was an unfortunate linebreak when I read that part.